# All solution packages copied to output for single project

Tags: visual-studio, nuget

I have a solution that contains a primary .NET project (WPF desktop application) and several library projects (i.e. plugins). Each of these projects contains (non-overlapping) references to NuGet packages (installed using the PackageReference mechanic). For example:

- `WpfApplication` References:

  - `MaterialDesignThemes`
  - `MvvmValidation`
  - `System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow`
- `Plugin1` References:

  - `Newtonsoft.Json`
  - `WpfApplication` (copy local=False)
- `Plugin2` References:

  - `Accord.Video.FFMPEG`
  - `WpfApplication` (copy local=False)

But when I build `Plugin1`, the build directory (a subdirectory of the `WpfApplication` build directory) contains the union of the packages referenced in `WpfApplication` and `Plugin1` (but not packages defined in `Plugin2`).

Similarly, when I build `Plugin2`, the build directory (again, a subdirectory of the `WpfApplication` build directory) contains the union of the packages referenced in `WpfApplication` and `Plugin2` (but not packages defined in `Plugin1`).

I did not have this problem with older style `packages.config`.

These extra packages amount to >100 files and ~15MB of disk space per plugin! How can I stop this from happening?

Answer (score 0):

Please try to add the tag "ExcludeAssets" (These assets will not be consumed) with the PackageReference node inside the wpfapplication config file like the following:
[image]

After that, build the Plugin1/2 to test it again. For more detail information, please check [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/package-references-in-project-files#using-packagereference-for-a-project-with-no-packagereferences).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I applied the element and value you suggest, but this causes the WPF application to fail building. The compiler cannot seem to find any of the packages. This also prevents building the plugins as they depend on WPF application.

Comment: @Josh, could you please share the detail content of your WPF application .csproj and the detail build error message? You can also try to create a new WPF application  and edit the .csproj file and add the <ItemGroup> node like my shared screenshot to test this package.